# Simple string-to-wildcard comparison in Python

Tags: python, string, compare, wildcard

I've been looking for a while but failed to find a simple solution for problems like these:

```
pattern = '20*_*_*'
compare('2023_01_01', pattern)
>>> True

compare('1999_01_01', pattern)
>>> False
```

I know how to do it with regex, but would like to know if there's an easier and more readable way to do it.

Comment: This quite literaly the perfect usecase for Regex, why would you do it in any other way? Regex is pretty readable if you get used to it. Try using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to build your regex, that usually helps me a lot.

Comment: @Kraay89, I am writing code that is being used by people who do not code every day. Thanks for sharing Regex101. I will use it to become better with Regex, so that my code will become more efficient and more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect use case for [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/fnmatch.html):

```
import fnmatch

pattern = '20*_*_*'

fnmatch.fnmatch('2023_01_01', pattern)
>>> True
fnmatch.fnmatch('1999_01_01', pattern)
>>> False
```

If you need case-sensitive comparisons, use `fnmatch.fnmatchcase()` instead of `fnmatch.fnmatch()`.